# "На все корки" — проихождение выражения

Tags: фразеология

Говорят "ругать на все корки" — то есть, распекать по-всякому? А откуда пошло это выражение. Почему — корки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Корить* - ругать, упрекать.

Фасмер:

Кор - "оскорбление, брань", только стар.; сюда же уко́р, поко́р "упрек, порицание, позор", на переко́р, ст.-слав. оукоръ ὕβρις, цслав. коръ, болг. кор, сюда же: кори́ться, по-кори́ть, укр. кори́ти "укорять, порицать", болг. коря́ "порицаю", сербохорв. ко̀рити, ко̀ри̑м "укорять", словен. koríti "наказывать", чеш. kořiti "смирять, преклонять голову перед к.-л.", слвц. kоrit᾽, польск. korzyć "унижать, смирять", в.-луж. po-korić; другая ступень чередования: кара́ть, ка́ра.