# Этимология фразеологизма "ругать на все корки"

Tags: фразеология

Случайно встретила в тексте выражение "ругать на все корки".

Раньше я его не слышала, но в Нацкорпусе много примеров. Каково  происхождение фразеологизма и можно ли его услышать в современной речи?

Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vera, так обсуждалось уже.
["На все корки" — проихождение выражения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/16877)

Мне не до конца понятны нынешние правила ресурса, надо ли в таких случаях отвечать заново, или достаточно ссылки...

Ну я повторю вкратце. 
"Корки" здесь это не сухие края чего-либо. Это образование от глагола "корить", "укорять" - упрекать, бранить.

Т.е. "распекать на все корки" (вроде бы исходно именно "распекать", хотя не уверен) - это очень сильно кого-то корить, бранить.

Добавить по существу как-то и нечего.
Насчет "услышать в современно речи"... Ну в общем-то да, не исчезло выражение. Другое дело, что смысла его не понимают, как и вы, предполагая, что корки - это хлеба, например. 
Хотя, признаться, не уверен, что "корить" не родственно "корке" на каком-то очень древнем уровне.

(+)

Добавлю, пожалуй. Есть мнение, что "распекать на все корки" - это про выпечку хлеба. Когнитивная ассоциация тут понятна - хлеб сильно "прожаривают", как т того, кого распекают словами. Но как-то не очень верится в достоверность такого образования. Думаю - вторично.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, действительно: корить - корки, универсальный суффикс К,  сравнить:  нападать - нападки, обозначение действия с помощью сущ. pluralia tantum. А вот глагол корить не очень ясного происхождения, с корой/коркой его вроде бы не связывают.

Comment: Ну я и не говорил, что связывают. Сказал лишь, что не могу наверняка исключить. А на остальное - в общем-то не мои "копирайты".

Comment: У меня не было желания вас копировать, и обращаюсь в комментарии я, скорее, не лично к вам, а ко всем участникам. Просто сообщаю дополнительную информацию, которая интересна мне и. может быть, заинтересует их. В частности, я проверила по словарю: а) обоснованность словообразовательной  схемы; б) убедилась в отсутствии полной ясности в этимологии семейства слов корить, покорить, укорить, кара и др